# So i've been recommended Zend search lucene php for search functionality, but is it better than mySql full text?

Tags: php, mysql

i've playing around with mysql's full text search and I'm not sure if it is the best.

let's say I search for "how do I book an appointment?" it will give me the correct results from the database, so "how can I book appointments?" I think it is because "book" is an uncommon word.

What if the user searches "how can I schedule an appointment?" I find it will not retrieve any records.
I think it is because there are so many records with appointment in it.

So am I to understand a user can only get information on how to book an appointment if they use "book" in their question?

Lastly, should I be cleaning out words like "how","I" etc... in a mysql full text search? Should I be Stemming words as well?

Comment: Before you start implementing (or even _playing with_) search functionality based on either Lucene or mySQL's fulltext, you should take the time to become familiar with the way FT engines work, in general, and with the power and limits of their features regarding natural language awareness (stemming, noise words, semantic proximity...).  At the moment you seem to be confusing all these things and the question isn't very coherent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give a look also to SOLR